# How to use requests library without system-configured proxies

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

If I supply `None` or an empty `dict` to the `proxies` parameter, `requests` will automatically fall back to the proxies configured for the operating system as obtained through `urllib.request.getproxies()` (Python 3) / `urllib.getproxies()`.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://google.com', proxies = {}) # or = None...
print(r.text)
```

Specifying `proxies = { 'http': False }` will even cause `requests` to hang completely for whatever weird reason.

So how do I direct `requests` to perform HTTP requests directly, without any proxy ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out you have to use an empty string for the protocol you want to use a direct connection:

```
r = requests.get('http://google.com', proxies = { 'http': '', ... })
```

Weird, but that's life.

Comment: strangely this doesn't seem to work for me if I set it for a `Session` object, though it works with `requests.get()`
**Update**: using `os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY']=''` works

Comment: (this was because I was explicitly setting `HTTPS_PROXY` in my Windows user environment variables for pip to work)